# Dock previews are too small to see

Tags: gnome-shell, dash-to-dock

On a 4K monitor, the previews that appear when clicking an application on the dock are quite small and don't preserve the window aspect ratio. Therefore, for most applications (e.g. terminal, text editor), the windows are almost completely indistinguishable.

On Unity (which I just switched from), the previews take up the whole screen, preserving aspect ratio and rough screen position, which is much more usable.  Is there a way to restore this behavior in gnome-shell?

Alternatively, dash-to-panel allows you to see the original windows when you mouseover the preview, which is as good as the Unity behavior.  Unfortunately, pressing the super key in dash-to-panel brings up a search box which is impossible to dismiss, meaning I can no longer interact with any windows until I reboot.

I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: have you tired to scale everything up? or is it just the preview, that are small?

Comment: Using 'Scale' under screen display doesn't change the size of the previews; it just adds funny margins around them.  Even if it worked, however, it wouldn't be ideal: terminal windows would still all look very similar in preview, as the aspect ratio and screen position aren't preserved.  I don't really want to scale up my windows either.  I have a fairly large monitor, and I currently think they're a good size.